# Applying CSS classes on OPTGROUP elements

Tags: html, css, html-select

`OPTGROUP` elements don't seemed to be rendered according to CSS rules I define.

See example below, one would expect "Swedish Cars" to be rendered as "SWEDISH CARS" but this is not the case.

Is there any other way to get it done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.upper { text-transform: uppercase;}
</style>

<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars" class="upper">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars" class="upper">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wb6gJ/

Answer (score -1):

I could see text-transform:uppercase is getting applied for optgroup. when i opened the demo in Firefox i could see ""SWEDISH CARS" only..

Comment: Then I guess this is a Chrome bug rather than HTML Question... I am using Chrome (latest) on Linux.

Comment: Not really a bug, just browser developer preference I think.  I'm thinking, but I'm pretty sure the `label` attribute is the only instance when an attribute should be displayed, and it only is valid for `optgroup` and `option`.